# Re-Assigning an Autoreleased Object

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, autorelease

I'm building a puzzle game that has three different sizes.  The images that are loaded are dependent on the size of the puzzle.  For simplicity's sake I'll call them small/medium/large.  When I load my view, I'm telling it the size of the puzzle and I'm calling a loadImages method.

I have a property that's set up like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *solidSquare;
```

So in my loadImages method I have:

```
self.solidSquare = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:solidPath] autorelease];
```

solidPath is dynamically determined based on the puzzle size.

Now, if the user switches to a different puzzle size, I'm calling loadImages again when the game starts.  How do I handle this memory situation?  I feel like I need to call this at the beginning of my loadImages method.

```
[self.solidSquare release];
```

Do I?  How do I evaluate if it's the very first time it's loaded, or do I even need to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you don't (or it will crash). Since the object is autoreleased, you don't have to worry about its reference anymore -- it won't make its pointer dangling and won't leak memory. Also, when using properties, the property setter ensures the old object is automatically released.

All in all, you can safely reassign the property.

Edit: but you **do** have to set it to `nil` in -dealloc.

Comment: When I finished reading the question, you already had the answer posted. +1 for explaining what autorelease means and especially, that the property takes care of the retain/release. However you may want to mention, that it's the 'retain'/'strong' attribute, that does the magic in that case.

Comment: So I don't even need to release it when my view is dealloc'd then?  I guess that makes sense.  I didn't realize it would release the old object if it was reassigned, that's good to know.  If I wanted to manage this manually, would I need to evaluate if solidSquare == nil and if so, release it before assigning it?

Comment: @JamesB41 you have to set it to `nil` in dealloc. See update.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why?  What does setting an object to nil do vs. releasing it?

Comment: @JamesB41 you do not set the *object* to nil, you set the *property* to nil. As **I have already explained it**, the property setter releases the old object when setting a new, and retains the new one. Thus, when you set a property to nil, you effectively release the old object and then do noting (`[nil retain]` is a no-op).

Answer (score 0):

When you call autorelease, it adds the object to the autorelease pool, so you don't need to release it explicitly. If you would like to have control over when the object is released, don't call autorelease and release the object wherever you see fit.

Comment: You should never release properties explicitly outside of dealloc, and there you use the backing ivar. Always use the property setter and assign nil.

Comment: I never understood that... won't that be a leak? Because the original object was never released and you're setting the pointer to nil, so then there's no way to release the memory (unless it's autorelease)

Comment: @JohnCorbett the object was never released, but it was autoreleased.

Comment: @H2CO3 in this case it was, I'm talking about the case where the object is not autoreleased

Comment: @JohnCorbett then you can't alloc-init and assign in it one step, you have to use `MyObject *tmp = [[MyObject alloc] init]; self.foo = tmp; [tmp release];`

Comment: why do you have to do that? why can't you just say `foo = [[MyObject alloc] init];` and release `foo` later? Maybe it would be better to take this to chat.